# Position text inside a flexbox item with background image

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I´m trying to position some text on the bottom on a flex item with background image. But i don't seem to get it moving.

```css
.fourthcontainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: space-around;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex41 {
  width: 320px;
  height: 280px;
  margin: 6px;
  background-image: url("../challenge/img/romance.jpg");
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="fourthcontainer">
  <div class="flex41">
    <span class="textimage"><h2 >Romance for two</h2></span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex42">
    <span class="textimage"><h2 >Feast for your visitors</h2></span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex43">
    <span class="textimage"><h2 >Picnic</h2></span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex44">
    <span class="textimage"><h2 >Grill party</h2></span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex45">
    <span class="textimage"><h2 >Celebration</h2></span>
  </div>
  <div class="flex46">
    <span class="textimage"><h2 >Kid´s party</h2></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

The other classes have the same attributes except the images.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You want to move "Romance for two" text at the bottom of your div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you want to achieve? Since all of `.fourthcontainer` child will have the same styles. I add a new class called `.flex-child`. Fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/ocfr7ksd/

```css
.fourthcontainer{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: space-around;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.flex-child {
  width: 320px;
  height: 280px;
  margin: 6px;
  position: relative;
}

.flex-child h2 {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  left: 10px;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}

.flex41, .flex42, .flex43, .flex44, .flex45  {
  background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/320/280/");
}
```

```html
<div class="fourthcontainer">
    <div class="flex-child flex41">
        <span class="textimage"><h2 >Romance for two</h2></span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-child flex42">
        <span class="textimage"><h2 >Feast for your visitors</h2></span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-child flex43">
        <span class="textimage"><h2 >Picnic</h2></span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-child flex44">
        <span class="textimage"><h2 >Grill party</h2></span>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-child flex45">
        <span class="textimage"><h2 >Celebration</h2></span>
    </div>
</div>
```